# DaoGenerator throws exception

Tags: greendao

I just started witg greenDao, but i can't initialize the DaoGenerator : calling `new DaoGenerator();` throws the exception

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   at de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator.(DaoGenerator.java:60)

Here is my code:

```
    Schema schema = new Schema(1,"com.emt.testdb.greendao");
    schema.setDefaultJavaPackageTest("com.emt.testdb.greendao.test");
    schema.setDefaultJavaPackageDao("com.emt.testdb.greendao.dao");
    Entity user = schema.addEntity("User");
    user.addIdProperty();
    user.addStringProperty("name");
    user.addStringProperty("password");
    user.addIntProperty("yearOfBirth");
    DaoGenerator daoGenerator = null;
    try
    {
        daoGenerator = new DaoGenerator();
       // daoGenerator.generateAll(schema, "../project/src-gen");
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

many thanks for your help!